# AWS boto3 S3 delete_objects fails to Unable to parse XML response

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a a batch delete, deleting over 100 records so I am chunking the request. The error is below this error occurs INFREQUENTLY, I would say 1 out of 200 requests. This is in a AWS Glue job so at this time I do not have better logging. But I am guessing at what is happening is that it is deleting a file the does not exist anymore.

S3 Permissions are not a problem.

What exactly is happening here? How does one prevent this? It is currently causing an error and failing the AWS Glue job but I would imagine that it is the same for aws lambda.

```
class S3SlowDownError(Exception):
    """S3 Slow Down retry exception."""

def batch_delete_objects(s3_client, s3_bucket, s3_file_names: List[str]):
    """Batch delete objects."""
    chunks: List[Any] = _utils.chunkify(lst=s3_file_names, max_length=100)

    response = []
    for chunk in chunks:  # pylint: disable=too-many-nested-blocks
        response.extend(
            s3_client.delete_objects(Bucket=s3_bucket, Delete={"Objects": [{
                "Key": x
            } for x in chunk]})["Deleted"])
        keys = [{"Key": x} for x in chunk]
        response.extend(_batch_delete_objects(s3_client=s3_client, s3_bucket=s3_bucket, keys=keys))
        # response.extend(
        #     s3_client.delete_objects(Bucket=s3_bucket, Delete={"Objects": [{
        #         "Key": x
        #     } for x in chunk]})["Deleted"])
    logger.info("Deleted files in paths: {files}".format(files=list(set([os.path.dirname(x["Key"])
                                                                         for x in response]))))
    return response


@tenacity.retry(
    retry=tenacity.retry_if_exception_type(exception_types=(S3SlowDownError)),
    wait=tenacity.wait_random_exponential(multiplier=0.5),
    stop=tenacity.stop_after_attempt(max_attempt_number=5),
    reraise=True,
    after=tenacity.after_log(logger, logging.INFO),
)
def _batch_delete_objects(s3_client, s3_bucket, keys: List[Any]):
    """Batch delete objects with retry."""
    try:
        response = s3_client.delete_objects(Bucket=s3_bucket, Delete={"Objects": keys})
        # we are deleting the object if the delete fails because object
        # does not exist we do not want to fail since we are deleting anyway
        if "Deleted" in response:
            return response["Deleted"]
        return []
    except ClientError as ce:
        if ce.response["Error"]["Code"] == "SlowDown":
            raise S3SlowDownError()
        raise ce
```

Python stacktrace:

```
ERROR:root:ResponseParserError - Unable to parse response (no element found: line 2, column 0), invalid XML received:
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 433, in _parse_xml_string_to_dom
    root = parser.close()
  File "<string>", line None
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 2, column 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/main_etl_script.py", line 31, in main_handler
    spark_session=spark)
  File "/tmp/<app>.zip/run_bundle_etl.py", line 638, in run_bundle_etl
    raise e
  File "/tmp/<app>.zip/run_bundle_etl.py", line 441, in run_bundle_etl
    s3_table_prefix=syndicated_data.s3_storage_prefix,
  File "/tmp/<app>.zip/s3.py", line 141, in cleanup_overwrite_staging_files
    s3_file_names=[x["Key"] for x in files],
  File "/tmp/<app>.zip/s3.py", line 30, in batch_delete_objects
    } for x in chunk]})["Deleted"])
  File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 613, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
  File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 632, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 148, in _send_request
    request, operation_model, context)
  File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 167, in _get_response
    request, operation_model)
  File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 218, in _do_get_response
    response_dict, operation_model.output_shape)
  File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 242, in parse
    parsed = self._do_parse(response, shape)
  File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 775, in _do_parse
    self._parse_payload(response, shape, member_shapes, final_parsed)
  File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 811, in _parse_payload
    original_parsed = self._initial_body_parse(response['body'])
  File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 897, in _initial_body_parse
    return self._parse_xml_string_to_dom(xml_string)
  File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 437, in _parse_xml_string_to_dom
    "invalid XML received:\n%s" % (e, xml_string))
botocore.parsers.ResponseParserError: Unable to parse response (no element found: line 2, column 0), invalid XML received:
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'
```

Comment: Deleting a non-existent object is always successful (unless, for example, you don't have the right permissions). Interestingly, the logged XML string is preceded by `b` which suggests that it's a byte literal rather than a regular string but I presume that's not the issue.

Comment: Is there any chance you're sharing `s3_client` between threads here?  I've seen this behavior before due to boto3's session or resource object not being thread safe.

Comment: I am not doing anything to explicitly share s3_client between threads and it should not be, but I am in Apache Spark so there are ways it could be shared between threads on occasion.

Comment: Have you figured out the problem?

Comment: i added retry logic with tenacity and have not received the error again, the exception is `from botocore.parsers import ResponseParserError` so i think it is throttling of something